# Removing any .DS_Store in GitHub

Tags: file, github, gitignore

I have a repository over at GitHub :

https://github.com/ludovicriffault/feed-tastic

And I can't remove the **.DS_Store** files in every folder and subfolder. I've tried many things like the file .gitignore and some answers here in Stackoverflow but nothing works...

Any idea to fix that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to clone your repo, and then

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -exec git rm --cached -f {} \;.
git commit -m "delete files"
git push
```

The idea is to keep locally your "`.DS_Store`", while removing them from the git repo.
The `.gitignore` will work only if those  "`.DS_Store`" are first removed from the index, hence the "`git rm --cached -f`" (see [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)).